# Using SMOF in Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress

I want to give a condition to select a category to show post from a specific category on my theme . Using smof framework I can not able to do this.

```
query_posts('category_name=hot&showposts=1'); 
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Is my code to show featured post from the category "hot" ; but i want to give a condition to select category from theme options.

here is the smof code to create select category

```
$of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "Select a Category",
        "desc"      => "A list of all the categories being used on the site.",
        "id"        => "example_category",
        "std"       => "Select a category:",
        "type"      => "select",
        "options"   => $of_categories
                );
```

How to use this function?

Answer (score 0):

this work

```
  $of_options[] = array( "name" => "Select a Category",
  "desc" => "A list of all the categories being used on the site.",
  "id" => "id_cat-name",
  "std" => "select category",
  "type" => "select",
  "options" => $of_categories);`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This answer has been flagged for quality review because it is what we call a 'code only' answer. It is not being deleted, but we'd like to bring your attention to [answer]. Thanks for your help.